# schedule_interval of airflow job

Tags: python, airflow

Hi if i want to schedule a airflow dag to run at 12:00 pm and 18:00 pm daily.
How to config the schedule_interval

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('example_dag_one',
        schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
        default_args=default_args)
```

i add 0 12 * * * (it means 12:00 pm) but how to add 0 18 * * * (it means 18:00 pm)

Thanks

Comment: You can use 0 12,18 * * * like in crontab.

Comment: This web can help you next time https://crontab.guru/